# Mysql using more than 4m rows to get 1 query

Tags: mysql

```
# Query_time: 11.041339  Lock_time: 0.000074 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 4033514
use mytable;
SET timestamp=1441090564;
select c.fetching_method,cc.book_chapter_id,cc.book_episode_name,cc.book_episode_number,cc.book_id,
ccc.book_image_path,ccc.book_page_sequence,cccc.book_name,cccc.book_permalink
        from book_source c, book_chapter cc,book_page ccc,book cccc
        where c.book_source_id = cc.book_source_id AND cc.book_chapter_id = ccc.book_chapter_id AND cccc.book_id = cc.book_id AND
        cccc.book_permalink='Dancing_Cow' AND cc.book_episode_number > '42' ORDER BY book_episode_number ASC LIMIT 1;


mysql> desc book;
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| book_id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| description        | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| book_picture      | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| book_permalink    | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| total_view_count   | int(16)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| thumbnail          | int(2)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| book_rating       | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fail_retry         | int(2)           | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
18 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> desc book_page;
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| book_page_id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| book_chapter_id    | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| book_image_path    | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| book_page_sequence | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_time_added     | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_time_modified  | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| watermark           | int(2)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| book_related       | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc book_source;
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| book_source_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| book_id           | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| book_source_url   | varchar(150)     | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| fetching_method    | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| source_book_name  | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| process_id         | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| disable            | int(1)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| source_group       | int(2)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fail_retry         | int(2)           | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc book_chapter;
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| book_chapter_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| book_view_count     | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| book_episode_number | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| book_episode_name   | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| book_source_id      | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| book_id             | int(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| book_complete       | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| total_pages          | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| chapter_view_count   | int(16)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| book_fix            | int(2)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| original_url         | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have a very bad join statement which cause heavy load on my server.
Is there a way I can improve this join statement to use lesser rows.

My this table book_page got about 1m records. How can I optimise to actually able to draw the data and not using that much record (4m), because the data I want is actually very little. just that few value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should always be doing is to use `explain select..` to see the query health and how the optimizer is dealing with the query. This would give you some essential informations like if you are missing indexes on the tables resulting full table scan etc.

Now the I would write the query using explicit join syntax instead of implicit, which you are currently using and the query would look like

```
select 
c.fetching_method,
cc.book_chapter_id,
cc.book_episode_name,
cc.book_episode_number,
cc.book_id,
ccc.book_image_path,
ccc.book_page_sequence,
cccc.book_name,
cccc.book_permalink
from book_source c
join book_chapter cc on cc.book_source_id = c.book_source_id
join book_page ccc on ccc.book_chapter_id = cc.book_chapter_id
join book cccc on cccc.book_id = cc.book_id
where
cccc.book_permalink='Dancing_Cow'
AND cc.book_episode_number > '42'
ORDER BY cc.book_episode_number ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Now you need to check if the tables are having proper indexed, note that primary keys are always indexed so you do not need to add them again, however from the above query you can have the following indexes in the tables

```
alter table book_chapter add index src_eps_idx(book_source_id,book_episode_number);

alter table book_page add index book_chapter_id_idx(book_chapter_id);

alter table book add index id_permalink_idx(book_id,book_permalink);
```

Note that if `book_chapter_id` is already indexed on `book_page` table you can skip this one, and more important - make a backup of the tables before applying the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with using the [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) statement to find out what's wrong with the query. Some of the question I'd ask myself:

1. Are there indexes defined on the columns being used in the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses?
2. The `ORDER BY` is usually a red flag. If ordering is important, I'd rather have an index that is already ordered in the necessary order (`ASC` in this case). [More here](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by). There's a second advantage with using a sorted index here: In one of the `WHERE` clauses, there's a `> 42` clause. Without a sorted index, the DB has to traverse the entire index to fetch all the matching rows. With a sorted index, this will be much faster.